# How to remove nested subscribe using rxjs operators?

Tags: angularjs, rxjs

How can we remove nested subscriptions here using Rxjs operators ?
I have tried using mergeMap, but I am unable to get the results from 1 obersrvable. Also I don't want to merge the results.

```
setInfoAccount(id: string): void {
    let acntId: string;
    this.infoService.getInfo(id).pipe(take(1)).subscribe((user: any) => {
        this.customService.getSessionInfo().subscribe({
        next: (data: any) => {
          if (data && data.hasOwnProperty('sec_account_id')) {
            acntId = data.sec_account_id;
            this.randomService.setAccountData(data.Data);
            this.randomService.setInformation(data.sec_account_id);
            if (user.user_id.id === acntId && ( 
                   user.userRole.role === 'BackOffice' || 
                   user.userRole.role === 'FrontOffice' )) {
                   this.isUserRole= true;
             } else {
                   console.error('Unable to get info:', data);
             }},
               error: (err) => {
                   console.error('Unable to get session info:', err);
             }})});
```

**Tried removing multiple subscriptions using Rxjs,**

```
setInfoAccount(id: string): void {
    let acntId: string;
    let user = this.infoService.getInfo(id).pipe(take(1),
        mergeMap((user: any) => {
         return this.customService.getSessionInfo();
    })).subscribe(user=> {
      console.log('Subscribe to outer Obs.[user]', user); // user provides me different result as coming from customerService.getSessionInfo. 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First: `this.customService.getSessionInfo()` takes no input from `this.infoService.getInfo(id)`, is there a reason those two need to run in sequence, not in parallel? Say,

```
combineLatest(
    this.infoService.getInfo(id).pipe(take(1)), 
    this.customService.getSessionInfo()
).subscribe(([user, data]) => { // do stuff
```

Second, if they *do* have to run in sequence, `getInfo` first and `getSessionInfo` later, you can glue them using `withLatestFrom`:

```
this.infoService.getInfo(id).pipe(
    take(1),
    withLatestFrom(this.customService.getSessionInfo())
).subscribe(([user, data]) => { // do stuff
```